# JSON - Expecting 'EOF', got ','

Tags: json, d3.js

On jsonlint the following JSON shows an error: Expecting 'EOF', got ','.  The problem shows with the comma on the 10th line.

```
 {
            "name": "Professional",
            "children": [{
                "name": "Professional Behavours"
            }, {
                "name": "Self-Care and Self-Awareness"
            }, {
                "name": "Medical Ethics and Law"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "Leader",
            "children": [{
                    "name": "Teamwork and Leadership"
                }, {
                    "name": "Collaborative Practice"
                }, {
                    "name": "Health Systems and Careers"
                }]
            }
        }
```

Adding outer square brackets, the JSON shows as valid.

However, I am using the JSON with d3.js which doesn't allow outer square brackets. d3.js also doesn't recognise the JSON below as being valid.

How should this JSON be properly formatted without outer square brackets?

**UPDATE**

Thank for the ANSWER, this works:

```
{
    "name": "Condition",
    "children": [{
        "name": "Professional",
        "children": [{
                "name": "Professional Behavours"
            },{
                "name": "Self-Care and Self-Awareness"
            },{
                "name": "Medical Ethics and Law"
            }]
    }, {
        "name": "Leader",
        "children": [{
                "name": "Teamwork and Leadership"
            },{
                "name": "Collaborative Practice"
            },{
                "name": "Health Systems and Careers"
            }]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple root objects, thus is not a valid JSON. The root can be an Object {} or an Array [].

In your case, I'd go for an Array :

```
[
    {
        "name": "Professional",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Professional Behavours"
            },
            {
                "name": "Self-Care and Self-Awareness"
            },
            {
                "name": "Medical Ethics and Law"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Leader",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Teamwork and Leadership"
            },
            {
                "name": "Collaborative Practice"
            },
            {
                "name": "Health Systems and Careers"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Or if you want the root as Object :

```
{
    "a" : {
        "name": "Professional",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Professional Behavours"
            },
            {
                "name": "Self-Care and Self-Awareness"
            },
            {
                "name": "Medical Ethics and Law"
            }
        ]
    },
    "b": {
        "name": "Leader",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Teamwork and Leadership"
            },
            {
                "name": "Collaborative Practice"
            },
            {
                "name": "Health Systems and Careers"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is valid, but d3.js doesn't allow outer square brackets.

Comment: @IlludiumPu36 I added an Object version, you would need to specify keys like "a", "b"  or whatever you want

Answer (score 3):

Because your JSON has multi root elements (apart from an extra `}` at the end). This is what it looks like

```
{
  ...
}, // <-- It expects EOF but gets ','
{
  ...
}
```

A valid JSON should have one root element, i.e.,

```
{
  ...
}
```

So, when you add `[]` it becomes an array and now is has single root element which is valid, i.e.,

```
[
  {
    ...
  },
  {
    ...
  }
]
```